# Conditional duplicate elimination

Tags: r

Given the following data frame:

```
   z1 z2
1   A  X
2   A  Y
3   B  X
4   B  Y
5   C  X
6   C  Z
7   D  X
8   D  Z
9   E  X
10  E  Y
11  F  X
12  G  Z
13  H  X
14  I  Y
15  J  X
16  K  Z
```

I am trying to find a more efficient (than what I've come up with) way to eliminate the duplicated values in the first column, z1, given the value in the second column, z2, is not a specified value "X". This is the output I'm after:

```
   z1 z2
1   A  X
3   B  X
5   C  X
7   D  X
9   E  X
11  F  X
12  G  Z
13  H  X
14  I  Y
15  J  X
16  K  Z
```

There are several posts here (and elsewhere) about eliminating duplicates based on multiple columns and I HAVE tried various forms of duplicated() and unique() but can not seem to hit on the right coding that does this.  This problem is a little different from other posts I've seen in that the rows to eliminate are based on a duplicated value existing in z1 and is conditioned on the value in z2 but the conditional on z2 does not apply when no duplicate exists in z1.  I have come up with the following solution using subset() but the problem is that I need to input the values from z1 that are duplicated to make it work. My current solution is inefficient because I need to find the duplicated values through another procedure first and then hard code them in to the subset command.

This is the data frame and code I've been working with:

```
z1=c(rep(c("A","B","C","D","E"),each=2),"F","G","H","I","J","K")
z2=c(rep(c("X","Y"),2),rep(c("X","Z"),2),rep(c("X","Y","X","Z"),2))
z=data.frame(cbind(z1,z2))

t1=subset(z, 
    (z$z1!="A" | z$z2=="X")&
    (z$z1!="B" | z$z2=="X")&
    (z$z1!="C" | z$z2=="X")&
    (z$z1!="D" | z$z2=="X")&
    (z$z1!="E" | z$z2=="X"))
t1
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `duplicated`, with `fromLast=F` and `fromLast=T` to determine whether a z1 value is repeated:

```
duplicated(z$z1) | duplicated(z$z1, fromLast=T)
#  [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [14] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

All that remains is to limit to solutions that are either non-duplicated or have `X2` value of "X":

```
subset(z, !(duplicated(z1) | duplicated(z$z1, fromLast=T)) | z2 == "X")
#    z1 z2
# 1   A  X
# 3   B  X
# 5   C  X
# 7   D  X
# 9   E  X
# 11  F  X
# 12  G  Z
# 13  H  X
# 14  I  Y
# 15  J  X
# 16  K  Z
```

Comment: This solution works very well. Some of the solutions posted appear to depend on the ordering of the initial data frame. That's my fault in providing a toy example I put together rapidly.  Anyway, in my testing so far, this approach appears to provide the answer regardless of the data frames ordering.  Great solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
> wh = with(DF, match(unique(z1),z1))
> DF[wh,]
 z1 z2
1   A  X
3   B  X
5   C  X
7   D  X
9   E  X
11  F  X
12  G  Z
13  H  X
14  I  Y
15  J  X
16  K  Z
```

Comment: Interesting. I'm wondering why this selected z2 = X instead of the other possibility when there was a duplicate in z1.  Is it due to the ordering?

Answer (score 1):

```
z[!(duplicated(z$z1) | duplicated(z$z1, fromLast = TRUE) & z$z2 != "X"),]

##    z1 z2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
## 1   A  X                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
## 3   B  X                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
## 5   C  X                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
## 7   D  X                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
## 9   E  X                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
## 11  F  X                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
## 12  G  Z                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
## 13  H  X                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
## 14  I  Y                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
## 15  J  X                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
## 16  K  Z
```

Comment: Make sure to check both `duplicated` and `duplicated` with `fromLast=T` to make sure you mark the first duplicated value, as well (see my response).

Answer (score 0):

It is actually pretty easy.

Creating the data frame:

```
df <- read.table(text="  z1 z2
1   A  X
2   A  Y
3   B  X
4   B  Y
5   C  X
6   C  Z
7   D  X
8   D  Z
9   E  X
10  E  Y
11  F  X
12  G  Z
13  H  X
14  I  Y
15  J  X
16  K  Z", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Now

```
t1<-df[!duplicated(df$z1),]
```

That will give you:

```
  z1 z2
1   A  X
3   B  X
5   C  X
7   D  X
9   E  X
11  F  X
12  G  Z
13  H  X
14  I  Y
15  J  X
16  K  Z
```

Comment: With the example data given that works but not if there are duplicates in `z1` which also have values of `X` in `z2`. It would have been better if the original question had data which demonstrated the problem described

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I think josilber has nailed it though.